# Who was the first comic book superhero to fly without technological means?

Tags: comics, history-of, super-hero, powers

We know Superman only started to [fly](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/92821/when-did-superman-stop-leaping-and-start-flying/92832#92832) in 1940/1941.

So who was the first comic book super hero to fly **without**:

- The use of technological means
- Any gadget or the like (magic carpets, Mjolnir).

By fly, I mean not just levitating in the air like what Doctor Strange does when he is meditating.

Comment: Is this comics as a whole or a particular universe? i.e. DC, Marvel, etc.

Comment: As whole, including DC, Marvel (timely), etc.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to [Comic Book Legends Revealed #270](https://www.cbr.com/comic-book-legends-revealed-270/), Namor the Submariner was the first in mid-1939.

> In his very first appearance in mid-1939 in Marvel Comics #1 (which was actually his SECOND appearance, as he appeared earlier in the year in a giveaway comic that never was given away), Namor the Sub-Mariner flew!

[image: The Submariner with some mildly ambiguous leap/flight] 
[image: More pages with ambiguity] 
[image: I mean, I guess he *could* be leaping...]

He more explicitly flew in his next issue, *Marvel Mystery Comics #2*

[image: Finally, clear flight]

These predate Captain Marvel's first flight in *Whiz Comics #5* in June, 1940, and [Superman didn't fly until 1941](https://www.cbr.com/comic-legends-when-did-superman-first-fly/) in *Superman #10* (and that was generally considered to be an art mistake as he didn't officially gain that power until later in 1943's *Action Comics #65*).

Comment: I could've sworn Action Comics 2 started with Superman saying "Whatd'ya know, I can fly!" after missing landing on a building in Action Comics 1, but I guess I was looking at a different version.

Comment: Why was Namor on a crusade against white men?

Comment: @AzorAhai: He's opposed to humans in general due to underwater explosives tests killing Namor's people, and the attempt at a counter-attack nearly leading to the entire race being wiped out. They're just all white men because this was 1939, so that's what 99% of the humans look like in the comics.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots So he's basically Aquaman?

Comment: @jpmc26: A much angrier Aquaman. :) Who can fly.

Comment: Depends on what version of Aquaman. =) He can be pretty angry: https://youtu.be/tNN1RKfHXoo, https://youtu.be/Chg7xuNroYQ Although he's never flown as far as I know.

Comment: @jpmc26 Namor came first. Marvel:Namor (1939), Aquaman (1941) so basically Aquaman is Namor.

Comment: @RodrigoGurgel: ^_^ Yeah. Marvel had a lot of firsts.